# How Exactly Does CSS Compute Relative Dimensions

Tags: css

there is a certain CSS behaviour that I want to understand better.  It's not related to a concrete problem, I just encountered it while debugging a website.

Let's have a full width image in a fixed positioned div.

```html
<div style="position:fixed">
  <img
    style="width:100%"         
    src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x300.png"
  />
 </div>
```

This renders the image in its original size.  So my assumption is, the browser looks through the ancestor elements of the image until it finds one with defined width.  But it stops at the fixed positioned div and can't obtain any results, so it lets the image have its own width.

But then, why does the following render the image at width 0?

```html
<div style="position:fixed">
  <div style="position:absolute">
    <img
      style="width:100%"         
      src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x300.png"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

According to my logic, the browser should look at the absolutely positioned container, but it has no width set, so it looks further and ends up at the fixed positioned container, from which it should obtain the same width (auto or undefined?) as in the first example?

Also, I couldn't replicate this behaviour with something other than images.  Do images behave somehow special in CSS?

[EDIT] I also don't understand why the following results in the image having its own size and not taking up the full viewport width:

```html
<div style="position:fixed;width:100%">
  <div style="position:absolute">
    <img
      style="width:100%"         
      src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x300.png"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If this is a Tailwind-specific feature, please edit your post and include the `tailwind-css` tag.

Comment: The minimal reproducible example is in the link, there are no Tailwind-specific features, I just used the syntax.  `fixed` refers to `position: fixed`, etc.  But I'll add a snippet to the post!

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are facing is called "cyclic dependency" related to how percentage works. In [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#cyclic-percentage-contribution) you can read:

> Sometimes the size of a percentage-sized box’s containing block depends on the intrinsic size contribution of the box itself, creating a cyclic dependency

It's a bit tricky to follow that specification so I will try to use easy words. It's clear that `width:100%` on the image means 100% of the parent element (containing block) BUT your containing block is a `position:fixed` so its width is also based on its content so we have a cycle.

In such case, the browser will first ignore the percentage width and consider it as auto (so your image will get its initial width) to define the width of the parent element.

The width of a fixed element element is defined here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width (absolute and fixed follow the same rules)

If you read the different cases you will end with the shrink-to-fit algorithm to define your width:

> min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width).

What is important to note here is the "available width" which is big enough in your first example so the "preferred width" is the one used.

So the browser will set the width of the fixed element to its "preferred width" considering the image having a width auto and this will make the width of fixed element equal to the initial width of the image. Later we resolve the percentage width of the image based on the one of the fixed element. In other words, its own width! that's why `width:100%` will keep the initial image width

Add some border and use a different percentage to better understand:

```css
div {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:fixed;">
  <img
    style="width:80%"         
    src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100.png"
  />
 </div>
 
 <div style="position:fixed;top:150px;">
  <img
    style="width:80%"         
    src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100.png"
  />
 </div>
```

In the above, the image will take 80% of its own width because the width of its containing block is equal to the initial width of that same image.

---

Now let's move to the other example where you have an image inside an absolute element inside a fixed one.

```css
div {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:fixed">
  <div style="position:absolute">
    <img
      style="width:100%"         
      src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x300.png"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

The difference here is that "available width" of the shrink-to-fit algorithm. I know this one is a bit tricky but since our absolute is inside a fixed element (which also follow the same shrink-to-fit behavior) the "available width" will be equal to 0.

In this case, the absolute element will end having a width equal to 0 and width:100% of the image applied to 0 will also give you 0.

If your slowly increase the width of the fixed element you will increase the "available width". See the below animation to understand:

```css
div {
  border:1px solid;
}


.move {
 animation:m 2s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes m {
  0% {width:0%}
  100% {width:100%}
}
```

```html
<div style="position:fixed" class="move">
  <div style="position:absolute">
    <img
      style="width:100%"         
      src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x300.png"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above I am increasing the "available width" making the absolute element growing until it reach the "preferred width".

Remember our equation:

> min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width).

We have `min()` that's why the width of the absolute is limited to the "preferred width" and we just saw how that width was calculated and it's the initial width of the image.

Comment: I've read this answer so many times and I wanna know what does `preferred minimum width` , `available width` , and `preferred width` mean ? does `prefferd width` means the width we specify or it's child dom's width ? 'available width' means the parent dom's width? and I've no idea about what is `preferred minimum width`

Comment: @Archsx check the Spec link in the answer: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width and you can find more details in that section at the end (before the formula)

Comment: take the first snippet in the question as the example. the link says 
1>"calculate the preferred width by formatting the content without breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur," ---> So I thought it means the fixed div has the same width with the image. 
2>"the preferred minimum width, e.g., by trying all possible line breaks. CSS 2.1 does not define the exact algorithm" ---> I don't know what it is so omit it

Comment: 3> "calculate the available width: this is found by solving for 'width' after setting 'left' (in case 1) or 'right' (in case 3) to 0" and the case 1 is 'left' and 'width' are 'auto' and 'right' is not 'auto', then the width is shrink-to-fit. Then solve for 'left' ---> so here came the question: left is set to 0, but what about right? and the width of containing block is the width of viewport? if so, the available width is the same as viewport so you said "What is important to note here is the "available width" which is big enough in your first example "

Comment: @Archsx in the question it's about an image Inside absolute element which is inside fixed element. It's all about the "available width" but the available width for the absolute element is 0 because the width of its containing block (the fixed element) is 0.
In the first snippet we only have image inside fixed element and here the available width is the viewport because the containing block of the fixed element is the viewport

Comment: @Archsx and note that in the formula we start with a min() so even if the available width is very big we always use the preferred width if it's smaller. The available width will be used if it's smaller than the preferred one (which is the case of absolute inside fixed)

Comment: " the width of its containing block (the fixed element) is 0." if we don't specify the fixed element's width then fixed element width is 0 ?

Comment: @Archsx no, I am talking about the examples in this answer. The fixed element contain an absolute element (an out of the flow element that doesn't contribute to the width of its parent) so the preferred width of that fixed element is 0 and we end having a width equal to 0 for that fixed element. This will result in an "available width" equal to 0 for the absolute element (its child).

Comment: A question came to me : "we end having a width equal to 0 for that fixed element" this result is from formula min() ? is there anything related to the equation `'left' + 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' + 'right' = width of containing block` ? I don't know how to use the equation, 'cause for the fixed element mentioned above, `left` and `right` is auto ,and no margin-left and margin-right , width of containing block is the width of viewport . don't know what `width` is  and  how to use the equation.

Comment: @Archsx read under that equation : *If all three of 'left', 'width', and 'right' are 'auto': ...* then follow what is written and you will see that *rule number three below* and in the rule #3 you can read: *then the width is shrink-to-fit * and then you have the formula of the shrink-to-fit with the min().

Don't take only that formula, it's the whole section that you need to consider and you have many cases.

Comment: I checked the computed attrs in dev tools and the fixed element width is 0 as you explained (preferred width is 0), but **how** to get left and right  value? it says left is 0 and right is 980px(width of containing block which is body) after I set `*{margin:0,padding:0}`

Comment: @Archsx the containing block of a fixed element is not the body, it's the viewport (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details) and left is not 0 but is set to the "static position" (*set 'left' to the static position and apply rule number three below*), it's 0 in most of the cases but not always. Then you find the right after solving the equation (you have left, margin are set to 0, and you calculated the width using the min() formula and you have the viewport width)

Comment: Got it. the min() formula actually have three elements : `preferred minimum width` , `available width` and `preferred width`, since the `preferred width` is 0, do you still calculate the other two ?

Answer (score -2):

The `width` of elements with `position: absolute` are automatically set to zero. You just need to add a `width` to the `position: absolute` div:

```html
<div style="position:absolute; width: 500px;">
  <img style="width:100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x300.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  So what width do elements with `position: fixed` get?  Something other than zero?

Comment: @fweth the width is zero, but it can change depending on the size the children. `position: absolute;` divs don't change their width based on its children

Comment: OK, that makes sense!  Where do people learn about this?  Sometimes it seems that MDN is not fully exhausting on deep CSS stuff?

Comment: I just played around with `<div>` and its CSS in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). I used `border: 1px solid black;` on the `<div>`s CSS to see where it was placed and its sizing. Also, a bit of it was just assumptions. And your joke about [MDN not deeply explaining CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning) was hilarious. MDN just has a hard time presenting the exact pages you want to see. Generally, MDN's articles are very in-depth in contrast to its simple API reference.

Comment: @fweth *The width of elements with position: absolute are automatically set to zero* --> this not true, there is a more complex explanation behind this. I will wrote a detailed answer to explain the behavior

Comment: ^ in the above code if you remove the width:500px, the element will not get width:0 like you said