# Why are two inputs within an inline-block element twice as long as one input?

Tags: html, css

Say I have this code:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

section {
  margin-block: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <input/>
    <input/>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div>
    <input/>
  </div>
</section>
```

The first section is about twice as long as the first one, but why? I'm trying to understand why this is happening. The same thing happens if instead of inputs I put inline-block DIVs.

Comment: add <br> after first input

Comment: @DCR it works, but why?

Comment: You shod add display inline block to your inputs not div

Comment: I put inline-block to the div to simulate the actual code that I have (a fixed modal window with no width set, so its width is what's going to be within).

Answer (score 0):

<sup>NB - I think this is a dupe... if I find one I'll delete this answer and close the question, but for now, I'm providing you with an answer.</sup>

Normally, divs are `block` elements, and inputs are `inline` elements, and so they take up, depending on the browser size, somewhere around 140px in length. Two inline elements would thus normally sit side by side in a div, and that div would span the whole length of its container. See the border for an illustration of what I mean:

```css
section {
    margin-block: 20px;
}

div {
    border: 1px solid red; /* for illustration purposes */
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>
        <input>
        <input>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div>
        <input>
   </div>
</section>
```

However, you've set the div to be `inline-block`, which changes how things display, naturally:

```css
section {
    margin-block: 20px;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red; /* for illustration purposes */
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>
        <input>
        <input>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div>
        <input>
   </div>
</section>
```

Now, the second thing you've done which completes the picture is you've set your input elements to take up 100% of the width of the container. Only it's not doing what you expect it to do... because the inputs are `inline` elements and the containing div is `inline-block`, the containing div is going to maintain the size it would for both of the inputs side-by-side.

You can see an illustration of it retaining its size here, even when the inputs are set to `width: 25%` each (with some HTML whitespace removed to make it more clear the inputs are taking up exactly 50% of the horizontal space):

```css
section {
    margin-block: 20px;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red; /* for illustration purposes */
}

input {
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>
        <input><!-- this comment is just here to remove the inherent whitespace between the two inputs
     --><input>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div>
        <input>
   </div>
</section>
```

And what happens when you have inline content that overflows the width? It wraps to the next line, and the height of the element increases to fit the new line:

```css
section {
    margin-block: 20px;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red; /* for illustration purposes */
}

input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>
        <input>
        <input>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div>
        <input>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I answered this and couldn't find the duplicate as well ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Link?

Comment: I couldn't find the one I am looking for. I have these: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63001886/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/69197449/8620333 but I know I answered a question like this one ... need to find the correct keywords